# Div goes outside screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to combine these 2 scripts:

- http://designmodo.com/video-background-website/
- http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Modern-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-Final-Countdown.html

However I am having an issue. On laptop everything looks fine, but when I resize windows to tablet/mobile size counters are moving above the screen. I was playing with different css seeting whole day but couldn't figure it out :(

Demo:
http://brandflow.pl/products/bootstrap/flow%20coming%20soon/video%20+%20round/

I thing it has something to do with position of DIV which handles video...

CSS:

```
/* GENERAL STYLES
================================================== */
html {
    height:100%
}

body {

    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%
}


p {
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:140%;
    text-align:center
}


ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    z-index:600;
    position:relative
}

.pattern {
    background-image:url(../images/pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
}





/* BIG VIDEO BACKGROUND
================================================== */
.big-background {
    z-index:550;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden
}

.big-background .big-background-container {
    max-width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:0;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}


.big-background-btn:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.20)
}

.big-background-default-image {
    background:url(../images/sunset.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:0;
    backface-visibility:hidden
}



/* ABOUT SECTION
================================================== */
.about-section {
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    color:#7f8c8d;
    background:#fff;
    padding:60px 20px
}

.about-section-container {
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:50px
}

.about-section-title {
    font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#3d566e;
    padding:0 35px;
    margin-bottom:22px;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:center center;
    text-transform:uppercase
}



a.about-section-btn {
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#34495e;
    background:transparent;
    border:2px solid #34495e;
    padding:10px 14px;
    cursor:pointer;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:.4s background ease;
    -moz-transition:.4s background ease;
    -o-transition:.4s background ease;
    transition:.4s background ease;
}

.about-section-btn:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background: #34495e;
}



/* SMALL VIDEO BACKGROUND 
================================================== */
.small-background-section {
    font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
    padding:100px 0;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden
}

.small-background-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    text-align:center
}

.small-background-title {
    font-size:40px;
    color:#f1c40f;
    font-weight:300;
    z-index:10;
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position:relative;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top center
}



/* SOCIALS
================================================== */
.socials a {
    color:#fff
}

.socials a:hover {
    color:#bdc3c7
}




/* MEDIA QUERIES
================================================== */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.about-section-title {
    line-height:1
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.big-background-title {
    font-size:58px
}

.small-background-title {
    line-height:1
}

/*.player{ display: none;}  -> If you want to remove the video bg on a specific viewport w/o plugin*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
.big-background-title,#colorize {
    line-height:1
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
.small-background-title {
    font-size:30px
}
}

.countdown-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);

}

.clock-item .inner {
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
}

.clock-canvas {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.text {
    color: #fff;    
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;  
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    width: 100%;
}

.text .val {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.text .type-time {
    font-size: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .clock-item {
        margin-bottom: 30px;        
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .clock-item {
        margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNJdPyoqt8U',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}">

```
<div class="pattern"></div> 
    <div class="big-background-container">
        <div class="countdown countdown-container container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>WE'RE COMING SOON</h1>
                    <h3>We are working very hard on the new version of oru site. It will brings a lot of new features. Stay tuned!</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clock row">
                <div class="clock-item clock-days countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div id="canvas-days" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                            <div class="text">
                                <p class="val">0</p>
                                <p class="type-days type-time">DAYS</p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.text -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.wrap -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.clock-item -->

                <div class="clock-item clock-hours countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div id="canvas-hours" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                            <div class="text">
                                <p class="val">0</p>
                                <p class="type-hours type-time">HOURS</p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.text -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.wrap -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.clock-item -->

                <div class="clock-item clock-minutes countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div id="canvas-minutes" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                            <div class="text">
                                <p class="val">0</p>
                                <p class="type-minutes type-time">MINUTES</p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.text -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.wrap -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.clock-item -->

                <div class="clock-item clock-seconds countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div id="canvas-seconds" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                            <div class="text">
                                <p class="val">0</p>
                                <p class="type-seconds type-time">SECONDS</p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.text -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.wrap -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.clock-item -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.clock -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.countdown-wrapper -->
    </div>
```

Printscreen:
[image: tablet size]
[image: mobile size]

Comment: There are CSS transforms being applied on several elements to negative y values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `.countdown-container` has this:

`-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); 
 -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);`

set of properties.

There are other issues with the page, but for that specific thing, you should be set with adjusting or removing them.

Comment: Isn't that responsible for resizing circle size?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to add a media query to adjust for mobile on that div element that contains your counter.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em){
 .countdown-container{
    margin-top: 900px;
 }
}
```

That fixed the container and allowed it to be viewed from my testing. You would want to use this same media query to adjust your footer as well since it seems like there are some issues there too.

Comment: This could very well be a dirty fix, but it works. With the plugin you're using  there are indeed transforms and other values being passed in. So I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but this seems to work. I only tested in a testing environment and not on an actual device but *should* be the same.